# get & set the caret (cursor) position in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

Does anyone know a way to get & set the caret (cursor) position, in a contenteditable div? (not in a textbox)

This would be for IE & FF. Couldn't find any useful advice so far. The examples found have bugs.

Comment: The bug is: When I update the innerHTML of the contenteditable DIV I want the curson position to stay the same as it was before updating, meaning: I need a way to get the cursor pos and set it, in a div